# Is it possible to get gas to an island range?

Tags: floor, gas, stove, range

First, all gas/electric will be done by a professional.

I have potentially the option to put a range in an island. I'm on a concrete slab. Can I build a raised floor and have the professional run the gas and electrical under it or is it much smarter to run the lines through the attic and down a decorative pillar?

I'd like to avoid channeling the concrete if possible.

Comment: Will there be a sink in that island as well?

Comment: Nope. Just the range.

Comment: I put gas in my kitchen years ago - trivial (as far as these things go) because utility room with gas furnace & hot water heater is underneath the kitchen. But one of my neighbors was never able to do that because of split-level design with kitchen on concrete slab - just didn't pay to bust the concrete **and** the house design really didn't allow for raising the floor. If you can spare 6" of height to raise the floor then getting electric, gas & water all underneath is possible. Keep in mind though that there are access issues for certain things - both code & practical.

Comment: What about going through attic and coming down in decorative pillar?

Comment: Is this a full kitchen reno? If so, channeling the concrete is probably not that big a deal relative to the overall cost of the job. Plus, jurisdiction depending, you'll probably have to supply electrical to the island anyway, so there's that.

Comment: Ya pretty much full reno. I probably would need to channel 8 feet or so. Not to far. Can I do the channeling? Im guessing rent a concrete saw

Comment: Are you sure you will never want a sink in this island, and nobody else in the future will either?

Comment: Yes. Not enough room for range and sink.